# Remove non-existent language directory from URLs under nginx

Tags: url, url-rewriting, nginx

I've got URLs like this:

```
/lang/path-to-file.ext
```

and I want to remove the "lang" because it doesn't exist:

```
/path-to-file.ext
```

How do I do that on an nginx server?